# One div dynamic height one div remaining height and scroll

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs inside a parent:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="foo1"></div>
    <div class="foo2"></div>
</div>
```

`foo1` will have a dynamic height, so I can't use the style below:

```
height: calc(100% - foo1Height);
```

Now, what I want to do is make sure that the lower child `foo2` never expands outside of the parent div, and to show the scrollbar if it gets too big. I would prefer CSS only solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use **flexbox**. no markup changes.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100px;
}
.foo2 {
  flex: 1; /*expand to fit*/
  background: silver;
  overflow: auto; /*scroll as needed*/
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="foo1">1</div>
  <div class="foo2">2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2</div>
</div>
```

Or use **CSS table**, additional markup is required.

```css
.parent {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
.foo1, .foo2 {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
}
.foo2 {
  height: 100%; /*expand to fit*/
  background: silver;
}
.scroll {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto; /*scroll as needed*/
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="foo1">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="foo2">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="scroll">2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```