# One div height depend on content another div height take rest

Tags: html, css

I have container height 100%; and two divs in it width:100%; I want top div  height to be depend on content. it will increase or decrease. and lower div take rest of height.

```css
div {
    width: 50%;
    height:100%;
}
#p1 {
    border:1px solid red;
}
#p2 {
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="p1">item1</div>
    <div id="p2">item2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try flexbox https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1323/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35100237/483779

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **CSS Flexbox**. Make your parent container a flex container and apply flex properties. Make your second child element `#p2 { flex: 1 }`. It will automatically take up the remaining space.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#p1 {
  border:1px solid red;
}
#p2 {
  border:1px solid blue;
  flex: 1;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div id="p1">item1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt expedita dolorum obcaecati animi voluptatem doloribus natus iusto quae assumenda molestiae? Cum dolorem repellat vero rem porro eos magnam, vel iure!</div>
    <div id="p2">item2</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!